# How to use JSON file as a database for HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

We were asked to build a project where we could only use JSON files to store our data. My data would look something like this:

```
[
{
    "aircraftName": "Boeing 747",
    "departDate": 1640173020000,
    "departure": "Metro Manila, Philippines",
    "destination": "Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia",
    "estDate": 1640777820000,
    "id": "Flight_0001",
    "occupancy": 4,
    "onboardPassengers": [
        { "passenger": "Person 1", "seat": "A1" },
        { "passenger": "Person 2", "seat": "A2" },
        { "passenger": "Person 3", "seat": "B4" },
        { "passenger": "Person 4", "seat": "C5" }
    ],
    "passengers": 15,
    "status": "available",
    "depDate": "2021-12-22"
},
{
    "aircraftName": "Boeing 868",
    "departDate": 1640875620000,
    "departure": "Singapore, Singapore",
    "destination": "Tokyo, Japan",
    "estDate": 1640875620000,
    "id": "Flight_0002",
    "occupancy": 5,
    "onboardPassengers": [
        { "passenger": "Person 1", "seat": "A1" },
        { "passenger": "Person 2", "seat": "A2" },
        { "passenger": "Person 3", "seat": "B4" },
        { "passenger": "Person 4", "seat": "B5" },
        { "passenger": "Person 5", "seat": "A3" }
    ],
    "passengers": 10,
    "status": "available",
    "depDate": "2021-12-30"
},
{
    "aircraftName": "Airbus A350",
    "departDate": 1640875860000,
    "departure": "Jakarta, Indonesia",
    "destination": "Bangkok, Thailand",
    "estDate": 1640875860000,
    "id": "Flight_0003",
    "occupancy": 0,
    "onboardPassengers": [],
    "passengers": 15,
    "status": "available",
    "depDate": "2021-12-30"
},
{
    "aircraftName": "Airbus A220",
    "departDate": 1640876040000,
    "departure": "Tokyo, Japan",
    "destination": "Beijing, China",
    "estDate": 1641624840000,
    "id": "Flight_0004",
    "occupancy": 0,
    "onboardPassengers": [],
    "passengers": 15,
    "status": "available",
    "depDate": "2021-12-30"
},
{
    "aircraftName": "Airbus A220",
    "departDate": 1640876040000,
    "departure": "Tokyo, Japan",
    "destination": "Beijing, China",
    "estDate": 1641624840000,
    "id": "Flight_0005",
    "occupancy": 0,
    "onboardPassengers": [],
    "passengers": 10,
    "status": "available",
    "depDate": "2021-12-30"
}]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write and read a JSON file using JavaScript since I am building a browser-based application and not a node js one. Can someone give some recommendations on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Why not ask the people who asked you to build the project? Consider using the [Storage API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Storage_API).

Comment: `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are available in vanilla JavaScript. You can also use *jQuery* to do that. In a web-based app, in most cases an Ajax request is made to the server and it often returns data in JSON format, which is smaller and easier to read than XML. If the data has to be stored locally, as Sebastien mentionned, you can store it locally in the browser. But if it has to be saved in the signed-in user's account then you'll have to post it to your server and save it in whatever format behind (*MySQL*, *PHP*, *NodeJS* or any other backend technology).

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies, guys. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can access your JSON file data like this

```
let db;
function fetchDB() {
    if (db) return Promise.resolve(db);
    return fetch("./store.json")
        .then(response => {
            db = response.json();
            return db;
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

fetchDB().then(d => {
    console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can also write contents for my database?

Comment: You can add data to the `db` variable, but that will be temporary (until page reloads). To write data to the JSON file you need to access file system, which is present in nodeJS.